# Calculation of generalized Artin's constants

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, conjectures, primitive-roots

Let $T(p)$ be the period of the decimal expansion of $1/p$, for prime $p$ (e.g. $1/7=0.\overline{142857}\rightarrow T(7)=6$). It is known that
$$T(p)=\frac{p-1}{t}$$
for some integer $t$. Then, Artin's conjecture states that the fraction of primes for which $t=1$ is positive and is given by Artin's constant:
$$
A_1=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\#\{p:\frac{p-1}{T(p)}=1\text{ } \ {\rm and } \ p\leq x\}}{\#\{p:p\leq x\}}=\prod_{p} \left(1-\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\right)=0.3739558136...
$$
Artin's constant can be generalized by considering the fraction $A_t$ of primes that satisfy some arbitrary $t$. My question is: Is there some known formula to calculate it for any $t$?

By searching about the subject, I found some articles that seem to give expressions for that, but they are quite hard to read and understand. Ram Murty in [this](https://www.mast.queensu.ca/%7Emurty/Franc-Murty.pdf) article and Wagstaff in [this one](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa41/aa4124.pdf) seem to imply that
$$A_t=\frac{A_1}{t^2}\prod_{p\mid t}\left(\frac{p^2-1}{p^2-p-1}\right)$$
But by considering the first 1,000,000 primes, it doesn't seem to give the correct result for some values of $t$, such as $t=40$. So, in addition to the first question, what are the limitations of the above formula?

Comment: I edited the notation in your question (changing $r$ to $t$) to be consistent with the notation in the paper cited in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is answered by Lenstra, Moree, and Stevenhagen's paper "Character sums for primitive root densities": https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4816. On pages 2 and 3 they write (their $r$ is $10$ for you)

> one can replace the condition that $r$ be a primitive root modulo $q$ by the requirement that $r$ generate a subgroup of given index in $\mathbf F_q^\times$ [$\ldots$] the prime densities for such generalizations can in principle (under assumption of GRH) be obtained along the lines of Hooley’s proof, and equal the ‘fraction’ of good Frobenius elements in $G$. However, the explicit evaluation of the entanglement correction factor [$\ldots$] rapidly becomes very unpleasant.

See Section 6, "Near-primitive roots" where for $r \in \mathbf Q^\times - \{\pm 1\}$ and a positive integer $t$ they aim to compute "the density of the set of primes $q$ for which $r \bmod q$ generates a subgroup of $\mathbf F_q^\times$ of exact index $t$". That's what you want. Their Theorem 6.4 answers your question, using 10 for their $r$ in the formula for $\delta(S)$. For example, to calculate the density with $t = 40$, you want their $E\cdot  A(10,40)$.

Their Theorem 6.7 describes exactly when the density vanishes and they describe in a paragraph before that theorem the difficulty of using the formulation for the density in Wagstaff's paper to determine if such a density is zero or not.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution! With my current mathematical knowledge, I don't understand exactly how I would compute the density values with what is said in the paper, let alone code it in Python, which was my final goal. But to know that there is a way to do it other than by brute force (checking the first $N$ primes) is really interesting by itself!